# How to manage PHP Parent/Child browser tabs. Pause Parent while allowing Child tab to execute. At child exit, Parent Tab has refresh ability

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, smarty

I have a PHP application that is using Smarty templates and that needs to launch a child task in a new browser tab while overlaying the parent tab with a `reload` button.

This overlay should work like a `pause` for the parent page.

When the child tab is closed either the `reload` button is seen to be clicked to force a refresh of the parent page, or an auto-refresh to rebuild the page is executed without clicking the button.

I feel like I'll have to add some kind of browser based JavaScript to somehow manage this, but not too sure how to go with this one.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You are talking about PHP. This is a server-sided language and can't control browser behavior. You need to use Javascript for this, but I doubt that what you want is doable. Do you have any example that works the way you want it?

Comment: If ultimately what you are after here is a way to refresh the browser in JavaScript then you'll want to use `location.reload()`.

Comment: PHP is a server side language and has no direct interaction with client side browser.